# document.write & return function

Tags: javascript, html

I know HTML fairly well but when it gets to JavaScript I am a complete newbie. Anyway, below is a function that I have created and works just fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(yourName) {
        document.write ("Hello" + " " + yourName + " " + "Welcome aboard");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    myFunction("David");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, how come when I change document.write to return it doesn't work? It says `undefined`. Let me show you what I mean.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(yourName) {
        return ("Hello" + " " + yourName + " " + "Welcome aboard");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(myFunction())
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    myFunction("David");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, I'd like to declare a variable named `msg`, that gets the return value of calling the function `myFunction`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it executes this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write(myFunction())
</script>
```

Here you are not passing any parameter.So, yourname is undefined.

In the next snippet:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   myFunction("David");
 </script>
```

you are passing the value, but you are not displaying it. So, again it is undefined.

code: http://jsfiddle.net/VvdWU/4/

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to pass a parameter, like:

```
document.write(myFunction("David"))
```

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/xsaNe00gGgG0Aa2tsM7a?p=preview

Comment: Oh yes, like I said I am a newcomer! Thank you.